# Algebraic closure of a real-closed field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

There is a theorem that says:

> $K$ is a real-closed field if and only if 
>   (1) $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $K$ and (2) $K(i)$ is algebraically closed 
>   (where $i$ is a root of $x^2+1$ in an algebraic closure of $K$).

**Question:** Is $K(i)$ an algebraic closure of $K$?

Comment: In the case of the theorem I would say yes, as by definition $K(i)$ is algebraically closed and contains $K$, and $K(i)$ has to be contained in any algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: $K(i)$ contains $K$ and if you assume (2) then it is algebraically closed. Any algebraically closed field containing $K$ must contain $K$ and a root of $x^2+1$. Therefore, if should contain $K(i)$.

Comment: for sake of completeness, I want to accept an answer for this question. Do you want to post an answer? @MathieuHuot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hypothesis of your theorem are fulfilled, then $K(i)$ is algebraically closed and contains $K$, and hence is an algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: It's also important that $K(i)$ is algebraic over $K$ (which is clear, but ought to be pointed out)